# Find shortest paths between two groups of a graph

Tags: algorithms

Let $\ G(V,E) $ be a simple directed graph with non-negative edges weights. Given a group of vertices $\ A \subset V $ I need to find an algorithm that for every vertex $\ v \in V \setminus A $ , it will find the shortest path possible from any vertex in $\ A $ to that vertex $\ v $

My attempt:

$\ U := V \setminus A $

I will set a new array of size $\ |U| $ with all of its values set to $\ \infty $ and then for every vertex $\ v_1 \in A $ I will run a modified BFS where BFS iteration will stop if it is needed to go through another vertex in $\ A $ . check the result of the BFS for that $\ v_1 $ and update my initial array with distances if necessary.

Comment: Is it necessary that these paths are disjoint?

Comment: No. Paths don’t have to be disjoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your edge weights are all positive and you are not stating that these paths must be disjoint, you can just apply [Dijsktra‘s algorithm](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra-Algorithmus) for every vertex in $A$ to every vertex in $V \setminus A$.

The algorithm works for directed graphs, too. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190592/is-dijkstras-algorithm-for-directed-or-undirected-graphs). An implementation can be found [here](https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-in-a-directed-graph-by-dijkstras-algorithm/amp/).